# Best way to Find the biggest Odd number

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here I want to find the biggest odd number from a given set of numbers and if no odd there, print effect accordingly. Here I am setting the value of even numbers to zero and then comparing it with the rest, so is this the right logic? I'm getting the desired results, but the value of variable having even number value gets set to zero. Thank you.

```
 x, y, z = 45, 61, 82

if x%2==1 or y%2==1 or z%2==1:
    if x%2==0:
        x = 0
    if y%2==0:
        y = 0
    if z%2==0:
        z = 0
    if x>y and x>z:
        print(x)
    elif y>z:
        print(y)
    else:
        print(z)
else:
    print("No odd.")

>>> 61
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an easier way to find odds:

```
odd = [i for i in [45,61,82] if i%2 != 0]
```

now to find the maximum :

```
max(odd)
```

This can raise an error, if all are even.
So:

```
try:
    max(i for i in [45,61,82] if i%2 !=0)
except:
    print("all are even")
```

Comment: If the OP wants to keep `x`, `y` and `z`, I'll point out for their benefit that `[x, y, z]` may be used, and their values will not change. (PS: Good, and `print(max(...))` so we see something!)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a function that uses a for loop to loop over the numbers, and keep track of the largest odd so far in a variable outside of the for loop. Then you can print out either the variable, or if the variable is still what you initialized it as, print "No odd."

```
def largest_odd(numbers):
  largest_so_far = 0
  for num in numbers:
    if num % 2 == 1 and num > largest_so_far:
      largest_so_far = num

  if largest_so_far == 0:
    print("No odd.")
  else:
    print(largest_so_far)
```